# Value double echo for some reason

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not too sure what's going on here but I'm trying to echo a value from mysql and when I do, it just shows double for some reason

Code:

```
$result = MySqlQuery('SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=1');
$value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo implode($value);
```

It displays 7373, the value is 73 in the DB.
I also tried echoing * instead of value, it also displays the entire row double.

Removing the echo there just displays nothing anymore so it's not like it's being echoed through another function either so I'm confused

Also the MySqlQuery() function is used by pretty much everything else on the site where it doesn't display double results as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns an array with twice as many elements as the columns you select by default (each column is represented twice). I assume that the [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) in your code is a typo.

To solve the problem, either use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead or pass one of `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and `MYSQLI_NUM` as the second parameter to `mysqli_fetch_array`. As a rule of thumb, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` unless you know you need something else.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to admit that I'm new to php, what exactly is the difference between mysql_fetch_assoc() and mysql_fetch_array()?

Comment: @user1071461: There's nothing I can tell you that the documentation and examples can not. In summary, `m_fetch_assoc` is a subset of `m_fetch_array`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it. There is no typo, I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc and it copies double the value. If i use mysqli_fetch_array it tells echoes 73737373

Comment: @user1071461: Then there's some other difference between the code you post here and the code that actually runs. Obviously `echo implode(array('foo' => 73))` will work correctly, so start from that and work towards the code you have.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, at least now I know that it isn't something simple i didn't understand properly about these functions